# Call Servlet with JAVA SE

Tags: java, xml, post, servlets

I have a question. I have to develop an Application with JAVA SE that call a servlet with POST request and recive a response from the called servlet.

My application and the servlet exchange an xml files.

My question is: Is it possible with Java SE invoke a servlet with a post request? Is there some resoruce that I can study where I can find some advice?

Thanks
Luca

Comment: Yes, and there are many tutorials, use your favourite search engine. Try https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-http-client

Comment: thanks tgdavies, I'll watch your tutorial, but I'm using Java 8.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using Java 8? -- it is end-of-life.

Comment: yes, in my company use this version...